# Gulp - Watch multiple folders and output to relative dist folder

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I want to use gulp to compile SASS for my custom Wordpress plugins.

All plugin folder share same folder structure:

**wp-content/plugins/pluginname**

> assets
>
> > dist -
> >
> > src - scss

**GULP TASK**

```
gulp.task('plugin-css', () => {
      // Main SASS Style Sheet
      const pluginSass = gulp.src(`wp-content/plugins/**/assets/src/*.scss`)
        .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
        .pipe(sass());

      // Merge the two streams and concatenate their contents into a single file
      return merge(pluginSass)
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
        return file.base;
      }));
    });
```

*Currently my compiled css file is being output into the same folder as the src sass. How can I output my compiled sass into 'dist' folder?*

Comment: I think your question title is incorrect. :)

Comment: oh dear!! thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do with the merges (so NOTE I simplified those out) but here is something that should help you get to putting your result into a dist folder where you want it to be:

```
var path = require('path');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {

  const pluginSass = gulp.src("wp-content/plugins/**/assets/src/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())

    // return merge(pluginSass)

   .pipe(rename(function (file) {
      var temp = path.dirname(file.dirname);
      console.log('temp = ' + temp);
      file.dirname = path.join(temp, "dist");
      console.log("file.dirname = " + file.dirname);
    }))

    .pipe(cssmin())

    // .pipe(autoprefixer())

  .pipe(gulp.dest("wp-content/plugins"));
});
```

[gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) is useful for these situations and always seems to be easier to use that gulp.dest(function... path manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `dist` folder to the `gulp.dest` function.

```
const path = require('path')

return merge(pluginSass)
  .pipe(autoprefixer())
  .pipe(cssmin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
    return path.join(file.base, './dist') // ← Put your folder path here
  }));
```

See docs here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options

Comment: Oh, sorry, relative to each file? I'll update my answer.

Comment: yeah relative to each file, I did try your original answer before posting, it output a dist folder into root of project..

Comment: hmmm, this is now outputting a dist folder into the parent "plugins" folder

Comment: I think `file.base` may be wrong. Can you try the other properties from this page: https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#instance-properties ?